Why do gt tables render differently in Quarto compared to R Markdown, despite consistent settings?
I am planning to move from R Markdown to Quarto for parameterised reporting, but one appearance issue has prevented me from progressing further.
In R Markdown, the preview of a gt table looks identical to the knitted HTML file:

However, in Quarto, while the preview of a gt table appears the same as above, the rendered HTML file looks different:

The table includes stripes, which should be FALSE by default based on the gt documentation. Even if I explicitly turn it off using opt_row_striping(row_striping = FALSE), the issue persists:

How can I resolve this so that the output matches the preview?
The full quarto code example can be found below:
---
title: "GT tables"
format: 
   html:
     embed-resources: true
---

#| message: false
library(gt)
library(dplyr)


Default gt table:

iris |> 
  slice_head(n = 5) |> 
  gt()


Explicitly tell gt to turn strips off:

iris |> 
  slice_head(n = 5) |> 
  gt() |> 
  opt_row_striping(row_striping = FALSE)


By default Quarto modifies some table properties when rendering gt (and other computational) tables, most noticeably adding a bootstrap class that includes row striping.  In gt's case you can disable this by using tab_options(quarto.disable_processing = TRUE):
---
title: "GT tables"
format: 
   html:
     embed-resources: true
---

```{r}
#| message: false
library(gt)
library(dplyr)


iris |> 
  slice_head(n = 5) |> 
  gt() |> 
  tab_options(quarto.disable_processing = TRUE)

```


